# Using the number in front of a string to repeat that string as many times as the number says

Tags: python, string, list, sparse-matrix, repeat

I am trying to create a spare matrix assigning 0 and 1 to different roles in order to match two different dataframes. However, I am struggling with the format of the data:

```
    data = {'Location': {0: 'Madrid',
  1: 'Barcelona',
  2: 'Paris',
  3: 'London ',
  4: 'New York',
  5: 'Berlin',
  6: 'Birminham',
  7: 'Tanzania'},
 'Description': {0: 'M3',
  1: 'P5',
  2: 'M3P5',
  3: 'M3',
  4: 'M3P5T8',
  5: 'P5T8',
  6: '',
  7: 'FT7 M3'},
 'Branch_A': {0: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, 2 Brand_Manager, 3 IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  1: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, 2 Developer, Cyber_security',
  2: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), 2 Accountant, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  3: "Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant, PayRoll_Manager, 3 Brand_Manager, 2 IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security'",
  4: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  5: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), 2 PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, 2 Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  6: '----',
  7: 'Auditor or Auditor(S), IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security'},
 'Branch_B': {0: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager',
  1: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager',
  2: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager',
  3: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager',
  4: '',
  5: 'Accountant or Accountant(S), PayRoll_Manager, Brand_Manager, Developer',
  6: '',
  7: ''},
 'Branch_C': {0: 'IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  1: 'IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  2: 'IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  3: '',
  4: 'IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  5: 'IT_Support, Business_analyst, Developer, Cyber_security',
  6: '----',
  7: ''}}
```

I managed to create a list of dictionaries so I can split every single role:

```
def extract_data(row):
    positions = row['Branch_A'].split(',')
    result = []
    for pos in positions:
        result.append({pos})
    return result

df['Branch_A'] = df.apply(extract_data, axis=1)
```

Obtaining:

```
df['Branch_A']
0    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { Accountant or Acco...
1    [{Accountant or Accountant(S)}, { PayRoll_Mana...
2    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { 2 Accountant}, { B...
3    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { Accountant}, { Pay...
4    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { Accountant or Acco...
5    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { 2 PayRoll_Manager}...
6                                             [{----}]
7    [{Auditor or Auditor(S)}, { IT_Support}, { Bus...
```

What I am trying to do is, where I have a number in front of the role, repeat that role as many time as the number says. The idea is to fill those roles with workers that I have in another dataframe, however I do not think that I can find a code that would understand that I want 2 PayRoll Managers for example. Also, in the workers dataframe I have some workers that are Auditor and others who are Auditor(S). Is there any way where I can write a code that will use an "or" operator?

Thank youuu

Comment: Why do you transform to a list of set?

Comment: I do not have repeated values, why should I transform it to a list of set?

Comment: It's what your code do... `.append({pos})` <- you add a set

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Each row at the "Positions" column contains a single long strings with all the roles in one single string. So I thought I needed to separate every single role in order to be able to match them individually with other dataframe that contains employees ID and individual columns (0,1) for every single role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you expect it's not really clear but you can use the following code as starting point to extract number of roles per location

```
pat = r'(?P<Number>\d*)?\s*(?P<Role>[^,]+),?\s*'
out = df2.melt(['Location', 'Description'], var_name='Branch', value_name='Positions')
out = out.join(out.pop('Positions').str.extractall(pat).fillna(1).droplevel(1))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
     Location Description    Branch Number                         Role
0      Madrid          M3  Branch_A      1        Auditor or Auditor(S)
0      Madrid          M3  Branch_A      1  Accountant or Accountant(S)
0      Madrid          M3  Branch_A      1              PayRoll_Manager
0      Madrid          M3  Branch_A      2                Brand_Manager
0      Madrid          M3  Branch_A      3                   IT_Support
..        ...         ...       ...    ...                          ...
21     Berlin        P5T8  Branch_C      1             Business_analyst
21     Berlin        P5T8  Branch_C      1                    Developer
21     Berlin        P5T8  Branch_C      1               Cyber_security
22  Birminham              Branch_C      1                         ----
23   Tanzania      FT7 M3  Branch_C    NaN                          NaN

[88 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Oh Thank you, I think that is what I am looking for. If I apply this code to the data I provided here (it is a short version) is working well. However in the real data which have more columns is giving me the following error: "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". Why is this happening? the index of the df is unique, so I don't know why this is happening

Comment: The real data has more columns...

Comment: I updated my answer because there is an error but I think it doesn't change your error. Maybe you can share your data file?

Comment: I have updated the data. It is still a short version but with this I got the same issue I mentioned before. As you see, there is more than one branch. So my idea is to create a different df for each branch and apply your code. Once I have everything nicely organised like your code shows above, I will try to match it with the employee's skills from different df

Comment: Keep all 'Branch_X` are important in the final dataframe or is it possible to keep all records in the same column?

Comment: I can keep all branches in the same df or create new dfs for each branch but I guess I cannot put everything in the same column as I will then need to allocate the employees to different branches. Your output above is great as I can get a single role at each location, but I cannot see how I will get that in one column with all the different branches... I hope I understood your question

Comment: Yes, you get it. The problem is the length of your branches are not equal after explode. I will propose you something.

Comment: Hi, sorry foe the late replay. Yes, this last code is really good. I actually think it will work better for what I am looking for. I have tried it and it works well, the only thing is that the last string (last role) for each location is always missing, I dont see why as you have not drop anything on your code.

Comment: @Mike. I fixed my answer. Even if I didn't drop anything, I missed the last role of each row because my regex was wrong. I fixed it now (`,` to `,?`)